# Default setting permalink /blog/

Tags: permalinks

Does anyone know where to find the setting to disable (or adjust) the /blog/ section in the URL?
Other sites I manage don't have this default /blog/ setting.

I'm trying to set up the permalinks but it seems that the /blog/ part is fixed and only the path following can be set up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Marcel, is this a WordPress multisite setup you're working on?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the settings in the network admin options. Go to:

> WordPress Network Admin › Sites › Edit › Settings › *Permalink Structure*.

This is the slug to the settings for the site ID 1: `/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=1`

Comment: Excellent suggestion!